# CodeIgniter - save method and redirects

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a page to manage courses, built with CI 3.  When the user hits the save button, the form is submitted to the `save` method.  My problem is how do I redirect the user to the previous page with the form populated with the data inserted?

At the moment what's happening is that after submit, the save method loads the views of the `/new` page, and the URL stays as `/save` with the data populated.

Already tried the redirect, but it loses the data the user had inserted.

Here a snippet of my save method:

```
public function save()
{
    $this->checkIsAdmin();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', $this->lang->line('common_name'), 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->feedback_message->create('Please check fields', 'error');
        $this->baseInfo['page_title'] =  "Registar novo curso";
        $this->mybreadcrumb->add('Registar curso', base_url('course/new'));
        $data['schools'] = $this->School_model->listSchools();

        $this->load->view('web/top', $this->baseInfo);
        $this->load->view($this->templatesFolder.'tabs_start', array('courseId' => 0));
        $this->load->view($this->templatesFolder.'manage', $data);
        $this->load->view($this->templatesFolder.'tabs_end');
        $this->load->view('web/footer');

        /*redirect("/course/new", "location");*/
    }else{
        $saved = $this->Course_model->saveCourse();
        if($saved){
            $this->feedback_message->create('Success', 'success');
        }else{
            $this->feedback_message->create('Error '.$_POST['name'], 'error');
        }
        redirect('course/');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you read: [Re-populating the form](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#re-populating-the-form)? it explains how to repopulate the form field with the submitted data...

Comment: The for is being repopulated. That's not my question. The question is how, in the save function, redirect the user to the form, without loosing the data.
If i use redirect, then i loose the data. If i load views, then i'll come up with /save url with the form. And what i really want is, on the save method validate the form. If valid, insert on DB and redirect. And thats working fine. If not, then i want the user to be redirected to /new view with the data that's already populated.

Comment: Re-populating the form is explaining how to repopulate the form, but the form is sumiting to the same url/function, not to a function that handles the logic

Answer (score 0):

To re-populate the form you have to use the `set_value('field_name')` function in your `input` field like below:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" />
```

Return the previous view as:

```
$this->load->view('view_name',$All_Data_For_View);
```

Still If you aren't understand then read the CI [form validation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html) again.

Comment: The first part is ok. The second will result on loading the form on the save function, resulting on a url /save with the form populated. What i want is, on the save function, if the form is invalid, redirect the user to the /new view with the form populated.